# ZK Reordering in Listbox

Tags: java, zk

I will want to use reordering of **listitem** in zk How can we do it when we have  define tags(listitem,listcell) inside the **zul** file .I do Not want to use  **ListitemRenderer**.[Here](http://zk.datalite.cz/examples) i found something but may be they are not updating things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Listbox Reorder Columns

The folloing example could be found on [zk fiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/4k499d/1-Reorder-Columns-in-Listbox#source-4) too.

#### By Drag and Drop

First a dnd example that we extend to the popup way later.
The simple view:

```
<window apply="test.LboxViewCtrl">
        <listbox id="lbox">
            <listhead id="lHead">
                <listheader draggable="head" droppable="head" label="Col A" />
                <listheader draggable="head" droppable="head" label="Col B" />
                <listheader draggable="head" droppable="head" label="Col C" />
            </listhead>
            <auxhead>
                <auxheader colspan="3">
                    <button id="reorderBtn" label="Reorder" />
                </auxheader>
            </auxhead>
            <listitem>
                <listcell label="A1" />
                <listcell label="B1" />
                <listcell label="C1" />
            </listitem>
            <listitem>
                <listcell label="A2" />
                <listcell label="B2" />
                <listcell label="C2" />
            </listitem>
        </listbox>  
    </window>
```

The controller explained by comments:

```
public class LboxViewCtrl extends SelectorComposer<Component> {

    @Wire
    private Listbox lbox;
    @Wire
    private Listhead lHead;
    @Wire
    private Panel menu;
    @Wire
    private Listbox box;

    @Listen("onDrop = #lbox > #lHead > listheader")
    public void onDroplHead(DropEvent ev) {
        // get the dragged Listheader and the one it is dropped on.
        Listheader dragged = (Listheader) ev.getDragged();
        Listheader droppedOn = (Listheader) ev.getTarget();
        // then get their indexes.
        int from = lHead.getChildren().indexOf(dragged);
        int to = lHead.getChildren().indexOf(droppedOn);

        // swap the positions
        lHead.insertBefore(dragged, droppedOn);

        // swap related Listcell in all Listitem instances
        for (Listitem item : lbox.getItems()) {
            item.insertBefore(item.getChildren().get(from), item.getChildren().get(to));
        }

    }

}
```

Now we can dnd the columns.

#### With pop up

First we add a method that open up our menu if we click the button in Listbox.

```
@Listen("onClick = #reorderBtn")
public void onEditorOpen(Event e) {
    Window win = (Window) Executions.createComponents("/lbMenu.zul", this.getSelf(), null);
    win.doModal();
}
```

Of course we need a view for the pop up:

```
<window id="menu" visible="false" closable="true" position="center" width="400px" height="150px" border="normal" title="Reorder" apply="test.MenuViewCtrl">
    <listbox id="box">
        <template name="model">
            <listitem label="${each.label}" draggable="move" droppable="move" />
        </template>
    </listbox>
</window>
```

As well as a controller:

```
    @Wire
    private Window menu;
    @Wire
    private Listbox box;

    private Listhead lHead;

    @Override
    public void doAfterCompose(Component comp) throws Exception {
        super.doAfterCompose(comp);
        // get the Listboxhead in which we like to change the the col order
        lHead = (Listhead) menu.getParent().query("#lbox > #lHead");
        // set the model for Listbox box in the pop up
        box.setModel(new ListModelList<>(lHead.getChildren()));
    }

    @Listen("onDrop = listitem")
    public void onDropInMenu(DropEvent ev) {
        // get the draged and dropped again
        Listitem dragged = (Listitem) ev.getDragged();
        Listitem droppedOn = (Listitem) ev.getTarget();

        // then get their indexes.
        int from = box.getItems().indexOf(dragged);
        int to = box.getItems().indexOf(droppedOn);

        // swap the positions
        lHead.insertBefore(lHead.getChildren().get(from), lHead.getChildren().get(to));

        // swap related Listcell in all Listitem instances
        for (Listitem item : lHead.getListbox().getItems()) {
            item.insertBefore(item.getChildren().get(from), item.getChildren().get(to));
        }

        // swap the items in pop up Lisbox as well
        box.insertBefore(dragged, droppedOn);
    }
```

If you want to have up/down buttons instead of dnd, just take a look at this [zk demo.](http://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/listbox/dual_listbox)

### Listbox Reorder Rows

It is very easy and can be found quickly in [ZK-Documentation](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Data/Listbox#The_SortAscending_and_SortDescending_Properties) and on [ZK Demosite](http://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/listbox/sort_by_comparator).
Just add

```
sortAscending="XXX" sortDescending="XXX"
```

to zks `Listhead` component in your .zul, where `XXX` is evaluated to
 `java.lang.Comparator` by [data binding](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer%27s%20Reference/MVVM/Data%20Binding), [el expression](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Composing/ZUML/EL_Expressions) or set inside your [composer](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/MVC/Controller/Composer).

Comment: I am talking about Reorderding not the Sorting

Comment: So please define reordering. For me reordering is resorting and this is what is happening in your example and that zk doc is handleing in my link / I show in example example.

Comment: I already posted question with following heading:-ZK Reordering in Listbox not sorting in ZK Listbox.And in example you can see Reordering image.

Comment: You mean the little triangles show up and down right? And this is what you can see on the demo page of my awnser as well, triangle up means `sortAscending` is applyed triangle down means `sortDescending` is applyed. Just see the Demo and click on the head.

Comment: Ahh ok, so please be more specific with your question next time. Do you want drag and drop or an popup like in example? Both are easy I edit after you tell me your wish master :).

Comment: I will want to same pop up kind of thing but listitem and listcell will be in Zul page

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21646/discussion-between-subodh-and-nabil-a)

Comment: Thanks Man Is it possible for u to give the demo war of your code

Comment: Because i will took idea from your code and i will open the Popup Window and then user will select header from that pop window and chosse which he will want to see

Comment: I added all my files to [zkfiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/4k499d/1-Reorder-Columns-in-Listbox#source-4).

Comment: Ok let me try and let you know my question and thanks for ur help

Comment: Ok let me try and let you know my question and thanks for ur help.Can it possible to hide header any header as shown in link posted by me as right now i am doing same thing but   each developer have to write write rendered method but developer have to write hundreds of lines which is very hectic

Comment: No Framework = 1000 lines of code, Framework = 100 lines of code, CMS = no code. So if you choose zk, remember it is a framework. But of course collecting and using code snippets, your own zk related classes and own zk components should help. But we are getting off topic, so let us stop talking and if you like my anwnser plese do not forget to accept it.

Comment: I need some help from you How can i contact you?

Comment: i already saw that but there is nthing to contact you i need help in same reordering i asked another question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21765/discussion-between-subodh-and-nabil-a)

Answer (score 0):

I have done reordering in ZUL itself you can check [Here](http://zkframeworkhint.blogspot.in/2013/01/zk-listbox-with-column-reordering-in-zul.html)