# Changing the order of columns in ZK

Tags: java, zk

I have created in ZK a table with several columns. I have used the `listbox`, `listhead`, `listeheader`, `listitem` and `listcells` components. I would like to change dynamically the order of the columns of the table. Does anyone know if it's possible with the libraries provided by ZK? Thanks in advance

Comment: If you can access the Listbox, you can use Java code to manipulate it. So, it is definitely possible. However, as far as I know, it is not as easy as a single call that would switch positions. If you render the Listbox in Java code (as opposed to zul), you could simply re-render it in the new order.

Comment: Dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14021298/zk-reordering-in-listbox/14021556#14021556

Answer (score 1):

I have done reordering in ZUL itself you can check  [ZK Reordering Example](http://zkframeworkhint.blogspot.in/2013/01/zk-listbox-with-column-reordering-in-zul.html)